# Dense Linear Algebra C/C++ library for distributed computing

Tags: open-source, library, c++, math, distributed

My goal is to ***invert a large dense matrix in a distributed environment.***

I would like a library which would be "easily" integrated in a C++ application, thus it would be ideal that the library has a C/C++ interface or/and implementation.

A good candidate was [ScalaPACK](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/), but what I need is in Fortran (awaiting confirmation from the developers).

Another good candidate was [SuperLU](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/), but it is for sparse matrices.

---

PS - "distributed-computing" and "linear-algebra" would be nice to exist as tags, but I do not have the rep to create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I got

[image]
[image]

I would happy to know that there is more.

Answer (score 2):

The main contender for replacing ScaLAPACK seems to be [SLATE](https://icl.utk.edu/slate/) ([repository](https://bitbucket.org/icl/slate/src), [manual](https://icl.utk.edu/files/publications/2020/icl-utk-1437-2020.pdf)). It targets distributed systems (including accelerators) for dense linear algebra. It is implemented in C++ and provides additional C and Fortran APIs.